# Como recarregar o browser (Chrome) sem cache, além do disable cache?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cache

Selecionar o "disable cache" as vezes não é suficiente para que o browser não busque o javascript no cache.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Ou mesmo incognito.

Há algum tempo atrás eu usei uma maneira que mostrava a opção de esvaziar o cache no botão de reload da página, mas eu não lembro como era. Já fiz umas pesquisas e não achei. Não sei se essa última versão do chrome desativou essa funcionalidade tão importante.

Alguém saberia como fazer isso?

Comment: Se quiser fazer isso direto do codigo, pode colocar um numero `randomico` apos o nome do arquivo.

Answer (score 1):

Achei o que estava faltando e vou compartilhar pq talvez seja útil para vcs tbm.

1. Com o botão direito do mouse click sobre o símbolo de refresh do browser CHROME:
   [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
   Irão notar que nada acontece.
2. Porém se for aberta a opção inspect (ferramenta para desenvolvedores do chrome) o link de refresh da página vai ter uma funcionalidade extra (quando usar o botão direito do mouse), veja a figura:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui].

Existem outras maneiras para limpar o cache. Essa é mais uma delas. 
Em resumo, eu pensei que a funcionalidade tinha desaparecido dessa nova versão do chrome, mas continua lá. Só precisa abrir a devTools do chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Existe também os atalhos:

**WINDOWS/LINUX:**
<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> ou <kbd>CRTL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>

*<kbd>CRTL</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> esse também funciona comigo mas não tem referencia**

**MAC:**

<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>

*Fonte: [support.google.com](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/157179?visit_id=636811110864405438-4134103350)*

Comment: Você sabe como que faz o CTRL+F5 no celular?

Comment: No celular você pode ir em **Configurações** -> **Privacidade** -> **Limpar dados de navegação** -> **AVANÇADO**, marca apenas a opção **Imagem e arquivos armazenados em cache** e clica em **Limpar dados**

Comment: Caso seu celular seja um **Android** e ele esta com  o **developer mode habilitado** você pode usar [**a parte do navegador** nesse link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/404451/3774), e usar o **disable cache** do console do chrome de seu computador.

Comment: Em si não tem então, mas tem outras opções para conseguir fazer isso! valeu

Answer (score 0):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se isso não for suficiente, provavelmente o site/cdn está salvando cache do seus arquivos.