# Como tirar o favicon de uma página HTML?

Tags: html

Eu, coloquei um ícone na guia do meu navegador utilizando a tag de icon no head só que quando eu apago essa tag a imagem permanece lá, ainda mesmo atualizando fechando e abrindo novamente o navegador ela permanece lá e já fiz isso com outros documentos e acontece a mesma coisa, seria como o navegador salva-se a imagem. alguém me explica porque isso acontece?

Comment: Quando for assim, tem que limpar o cache do navegador.

Comment: Como foi dito por @LeAndrade tente limpar o cache do navegador, esse link talvez ajude - [Como recarregar o browser (Chrome) sem cache, além do disable cache?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/241960/como-recarregar-o-browser-chrome-sem-cache-al%C3%A9m-do-disable-cache)

Comment: Ele não tira o favicon você só pode trocar o favicon por outro.

Answer (score 1):

Além de remover o `<link rel="icon" href=""/>` do seu html. Exclua o arquivo `.ico` ou `favicon.png` da raiz do seu site. O browser pode acabar utilizando esse arquivo por padrão mesmo que você não faça a declaração no html, como no caso de requisições diretas a recursos estáticos.

Comment: Sim, tentei isso mais o navegador persiste com a imagem. Seria quase mesma coisa se usa-se o "locaStorage" para guardar dados no pc e só pode-se remover usando o "removeItem()" mesmo apagando o "localStorage" do código. Só que navegador parece que faz isso com a imagem. Já tentei de tudo quanto é (jeito) mais contínua com a imagem lá não sei se é algum erro, bug no chrome ou alguma função que faz acontecer isso pois testei o código sem o "favicon" em outros navegadores e eles ficam normais sem o ícone se eu colocar o "favicon" aparece de boa só que no chrome tanto faz eu colocar ou remover.