# Meu JavaScript não funciona na WebView, como posso depurar?

Tags: javascript, android, webview

Tenho uma página e estou tentando transformá-la em App pelo WebView. Gerei um apk quando cheguei na parte de habilitar o javascript, porém a página dentro do app fica estática, travada. Ao entrar no site pelo navegador, funciona perfeitamente. Ela abre uma tela mostrando nome e logomarca e em poucos segundos vai para a tela inicial. O que ocorre, é que no app, a tela fica parada nessa primeira tela (com nome e logo).

Como eu posso depurar a pagina na WebView para verificar o que esta ocorrendo com o código?

MainActivity.java:

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView.loadUrl("https://estilofacul.com.br");
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

    }
}
```

Comment: Provavelmente o site usa alguma funcionalidade mais moderna do ES6 (que muitas vezes é desnecessária) e o webView não tem suporte para isto. E não, não tem como forçar o webView a suportar algo, isso depende do motor.

Comment: Obrigado Guilherme, farei alguns testes e tendo uma solução respondo aqui..

Comment: Olá @Dani, editei sua pergunta para dar um objetivo mas claro a ela, caso essa edição não represente seu problema você pode [reverter aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/404448/revisions). =D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como [guilherme disse em seu comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/404448/javascript-n%c3%a3o-funcionando-no-webview#comment792568_404448), pode ser um problema de funcionalidade, fato é que você vai ter que depurar para ver o que esta acontecendo.

Você pode utilizar o Chrome Developer Tools *(DevTools)* para fazer a [depuração remota da WebView](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/webviews).

### PRIMEIRO PASSO

<sup>Fazer sua WebView ser *vista* pelo navegador.</sup>

Você precisa adicionar o seguinte código no seu aplicativo.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    if (0 != (getApplicationInfo().flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_DEBUGGABLE))
        WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
}
```

<sup>*Esse código habilita o modo debug da WebView somente quando o aplicativo gerado esta em modo debug.*</sup>

### SEGUNDO PASSO

<sup>Acessando o `inpect` através do browser Google Chrome</sup>

**MODO 1:**

1. Acesse o link `chrome://inspect/#devices`
2. Verificar se o **Discovery USB devices** esta marcado.
3. Entre as paginas que aparecer vai estar seu aplicativo, basta clicar em **inspect** nele e pronto você vai ter acesso ao console.

**MODO 2:**
<sup>**Esse modo parece ter sido descontinuado em versões mais atuais do browser**</sup>

1. Abra o Google Chrome
2. Abra o **DevTools**

   - Windows/Linux: <kbd>F12</kbd> ou <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>
   - Mac: <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>
3. Vá para uma aba que não seja o **console**, ex. **network**
4. Aperte <kbd>ESC</kbd>, vai abrir uma nova seção com o console.
5. Nesta seção você vai clicar em more tools ( os três pontos ).
6. Clicar em **Remote devices**
7. Verificar se o **Discovery USB devices** esta marcado.
8. Clicar em seu **device**
9. Entre as paginas que aparecer vai estar seu aplicativo, basta clicar em **inspect** nele e pronto você vai ter acesso ao console.

<sup>*Lembrando que seu aparelho Android tem que estar conectado via USB e com modo **USB Debugging** ativo.</sup>

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> ### Referencias:
>
> - [Primeiros passos com a depuração remota de dispositivos Android](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/webviews)
> - [Depuração remota de WebViews](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/webviews)
> - [Chrome DevTools atalhos de teclado](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/shortcuts)

Comment: Ícaro muito obrigado pela sua presteza e retorno.. Farei alguns testes